# Why a very simple google map application doesn't work?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am try to make Google map v2 application. I found lots of example and looks simple and strength forward. But unfortunately none of them work for me. I wasted couple of days and couldn't do make launch a map application yet. I configured prerequisites such as enable service Map 2 in google api console, Google Maps API key, download google-play-services_lib and import it in work space, etc. But always get FATAL EXCEPTION as soon as I call

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

Please help to figure out my problem. I think one has to examine my project configuration to answer this question. So please get the complete project @ likn removed. I also added a file named Google APIs Console.pdf where I took print google api console to show my api key is correct as well.

Please guys help me!

Comment: Please only post the code that is relevant to the `Exception` you get. Where do you think the source of the problem is? What does the stack trace say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Android introduces new meta data as follows. So we need it along with api key. So it should be in the AndroidManifest.xml inside  node as follows:-

```
      <application
      <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="your application key form google api console"/>
      **<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />**
     </application>
```